# How to login a site using webkit

Tags: python, webkit, login-script

I'm trying to do a login to yahoo mail. This is my code, but I'm unable to run it correctly.
Probably the struct of the script is wrong. Here I'm using webkit and gtk. If you know other methods to implement that function suggest me. Anyway I need to use javascript when logged in.
Thanks for your help.

```
import gtk
from webkit import WebView, WebSettings
from getpass import getpass
import gobject

class MyClass:

    __timeout=5
    __load=False
    login = ("", "")
    settings = {'username': login[0] or raw_input("Username: "), 'password': login[1] or getpass()}

    def connect(self):
        def onLoadFinished(view,frame):
            self.__load=True
        s=self.view.connect('load-finished',onLoadFinished)
        self.view.open("https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?.intl=it&.src=ym&rl=1")
        print "Loading yahoo.it"
        while not self.__load:
            pass
        self.__load=False
        self.view.execute_script("document.getElementById('username').value='%s';" % self.settings['username'])
        self.view.execute_script("document.getElementById('passwd').value='%s';" % self.settings['password'])
        self.view.execute_script("document.getElementById('.save').click();")
        while not self.__load:
            pass
        self.__load=False
        self.view.execute_script("document.getElementById('inbox-label').click()")

    def __init__(self):
        w_ = gtk.Window()
        s_ = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
        self.view = WebView()
        s_.add(self.view)
        w_.add(s_)
        w_.show_all();

    def callback(self):
        self.connect() 
        gobject.timeout_add_seconds(self.__timeout, self.callback)


MyClass()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run it? Do you get an exception? If so, please post the full exception and traceback.

Comment: It opens a white windows, but nothing else. The yahoo login page doesn't appear.